# Scalatra Set Response Headers

Tags: scala, post, header, scalatra

I am trying to set response headers during post request.  While everything compiles properly, headers are not set.

Here is my code:

```
post("/get_value"){
val jsonString = request.body;   

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE")
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600")
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, content-type")

jsonString
}
```

What is the valid way to set headers of this kind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Scalatra but you can notice that [ActionResult](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/develop/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/ActionResult.scala) is a case class;

```
case class ActionResult(status: ResponseStatus, body: Any, headers: Map[String, String])
```

3rd parameter of this case class is `Map[String,String]` which should be response header.

There is also;

```
object Ok {
  def apply(body: Any = Unit, headers: Map[String, String] = Map.empty, reason: String = "") = ActionResult(responseStatus(200, reason), body, headers)
}
```

Returns http response with status code `200`, you can create it like;

```
Ok("response",Map('HeaderKey' -> 'HeaderValue'))
```

As a conclusion final solution can be like;

```
post("/get_value") {
  val jsonString = request.body;   
  val headers = Map("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE",
                    "Access-Control-Max-Age" -> "3600",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "x-requested-with, content-type")

  Ok(jsonString,headers)
}
```